# Redshift "INSERT INTO" blocked during a separate COPY

Tags: copy, amazon-redshift, insert-into

I have been playing with Redshift recently, and found an odd (or maybe not so odd) behavior. When a COPY  (from S3) is in progress, if I do INSERT INTO in a completely different table in a different schema, the INSERT INTO query takes way too much time. When nothing else is running on the redshift cluster, the INSERT INTO query finishes within 3-5 minutes. But, when a COPY is in progress, the same INSERT INTO query takes 1-2 hours.

Looking at the Redshift dashboard, the odd thing is that read throughput is close to zero. Given that my INSERT INTO query contains a select, I would imagine that the read throughput would be higher. So, it feels like the COPY query is blocking all other writes. I have checked the LOCKs (STV_LOCKS) table and there is no conflict between LOCKS for COPY and INSERT INTO. Is it possible that the COPY query blocks all other writes?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to check parameter group configuration ( for your cluster in AWS console) -> Workload Management Configuration.

Check for concurrency .By default its 5 . you can increase the value ( max is up to 50) . This will allow concurrent connections. When you are doing copy command some of the connections are used so for insert into query , there might not connections left. So increase the concurrency and check again.

Hope this helps